Approximation of a measurable set in product space by rectangles from inside
Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{T},\nu)$ are two finite measure spaces and then $(X\times Y, \mathcal{S}\otimes \mathcal{T},\mu\times \nu)$ is the product space.
I know that for any $C \in \mathcal{S}\otimes \mathcal{T}$ and $\epsilon > 0$, we can find $D$ which is a finite union of measurable rectangles, i.e. $D = \cup_{i=1}^k A_i \times B_i$ where $A_i\in \mathcal{S}, B_i \in \mathcal{T}$, such that $(\mu\times \nu)(D \Delta C) < \epsilon$, where $\Delta$ denotes symmetric difference.
I am wondering that can we always make the approximation by rectangles from the inside? That is for any $C$ and $\epsilon$, we can find $D = \cup_{i=1}^k A_i \times B_i \subset C$ and $(\mu\times \nu)(C \setminus D) < \epsilon$. Is this claim correct?

I wonder if ${ (x, y) \mid \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y - x \notin \mathbb{Q} }$ might be a counterexample.  It would seem difficult to have any rectangles of positive measure contained in that set -- though I certainly don't have a proof that none exist.

Maybe: if $S$ and $T$ have positive measure, then we might as well assume they also have finite measure.  Then the convolution of $\chi_S$ and $\chi_T$ is a continuous function (by continuity of translation), and the convolution is also not identically zero (since $\chi_S, \chi_T \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ so they have Fourier transforms, etc.).  Therefore, there exists a nonempty interval on which the convolution is nonzero, and for a rational number in that interval, it occurs as a value of $x+y$ on $S \times T$.  Therefore, $S\times T \not\subseteq {(x,y)\mid x+y\notin \mathbb{Q}}$.

Of course, I'm a bit rusty on this stuff, so I could have very well made an error in that argument.

We can not always make the approximation by rectangles from the inside.
Here is a detailed counter-example (similar to what was suggested by  Daniel Schepler).
Let  $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{T},\nu)$ be both equal to $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda)$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$ and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.
Let us first prove a lemma.

Lemma: If $A, B \in \mathcal{B}$, $\lambda(A) > 0$ and $\lambda(B) >0$, then $A+B$ contains a non-empty open interval.

Proof: Let us define $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ by
$$
f(x) = \int_{\Bbb R} \chi_A(x-t)\chi_B(t)d\lambda(t)
$$
Let $\{h_n\}_n$ be any sequence of real numbers converging to $0$. It follows that
$t \mapsto \chi_A(x+h_n-t)\chi_B(t)$ converges pointwise to $t \mapsto \chi_A(x-t)\chi_B(t)$ and it is dominated by $t \mapsto \chi_B(t)$ (and also by $\chi_{[0,1]}$). It follows from DCT that $f(x+h_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. So $f$ is continuous. So $\{ x \in \Bbb R : f(x) > 0\}$ is open.
Note that, using Tonneli's Theorem, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Bbb R} f(x) d\lambda(x) &= \int_{\Bbb R} \int_{\Bbb R} \chi_A(x-t)\chi_B(t)d\lambda(t)d\lambda(x) = \\
& = \int_{\Bbb R} \int_{\Bbb R} \chi_A(x-t)\chi_B(t)d\lambda(x)d\lambda(t) = \lambda(A)\lambda(B) > 0
\end{align*}
So $\{ x \in \Bbb R : f(x) > 0\}$ is non-empty open set. So there is a non-empty open interval $I$ such that $I \subseteq \{ x \in \Bbb R : f(x) > 0\}$.
Now, note that, if $f(x) \neq 0$, there is at least on $t \in \Bbb R$ such that $x-t \in A$ and $t \in B$. So $x \in A+B$. It follows that $I \subseteq \{ x \in \Bbb R : f(x) > 0\} \subseteq A+B$.
$\square$
Let $C= \{ (x, y) \mid [0,1]\times [0,1] \mid x+y \notin \mathbb{Q} \}$. It is easy to see that $C \in  \mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{B}$ and that $(\lambda \times \lambda)(C) = 1$.
On the other hand, given any $A, B \in \mathcal{B}$, $\lambda(A) > 0$ and $\lambda(B) >0$, then $A+B$ contains a non-empty open interval, so there are $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ such that $x+y \in \Bbb Q$. So $A \times B \not\subseteq C$. It means there is no rectangle with positive measure inside $C$.
